# How to deal with .ch domains? I need a DNS

Tags: domain-registration, top-level-domains

I need to register a .ch domain, but SWITCH does not seem to offer free (or paid) DNS as other registrars do.

So I need to know at least one of these:

- Is there a registrar where I can buy a .ch domain, that also offers free DNS? Preferably not US-based
- Is there a really cheap and reliable DNS service? So the total cost for using a .ch does not go too high for me.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check [Gandi](https://www.gandi.net/domaine/prix/detail/CH/?lang=en) ? It's a french company that can provide .ch domain and lots of others services once you got your domain.

Comment: I used Gandi for many years. Then they started rejecting all my credit cards for no reason. I contacted them because obviously they had a problem in their payment gateway or something, but they didn't bother checking. Had to move to namecheap, which is awesome, but is US based.

Comment: You can pay using paypal too, it can be a workaround about your card problem.

Comment: Another thing: Gandi does not allow wildcards for email forwarding. I'm running out of options